# Question on why solution to combinatorics problem is incorrect

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

This problem is from the 2013 AMC 10A. I am confused on why my solution gives the incorrect answer.

> A student must choose a program of four courses from a menu of courses consisting of English, Algebra, Geometry, History, Art, and Latin. This program must contain English and at least one mathematics course. In how many ways can this program be chosen?

Here is my way of doing the problem: Since we know English must be a class, we essentially want to choose a math class and two other classes from Algebra, Geometry, History, Art, and Latin. There are $2$ possible math classes, so there are $2$ ways to choose the math classes. Then, however, after choosing a math class from these two options, there are $4$ more possible classes we can choose from, so we now have $2 \cdot 4.$ Finally, from the three remaining classes, we choose $1,$ which gives us $2 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 = 24$ possible ways this program can be chosen.

Can someone explain what is wrong with my solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Basically: you are counting English, Algebra, History, Art and English, Algebra, Art, History as different options, but they are actually identical.

Comment: @Dr.Mathva Either you choose the two math classes, in which case this yields $3$ possible choices, or only one math class, which yields $2\times \binom{3}{2} = 6$ possibilities, so the answer is $6+3=9$

Comment: Yes I understand that solution. However, even after dividing by $2!$ my answer also becomes $12,$ which doesn't seem to match up. Is there still more overcount I must take in for consideration?

Comment: Yes, that only fixed the overcount with the last two courses chosen. But I forgot that that way of counting would still not distinguish "English, Geometry, Algebra History" from "English, Algebra, Geometry, History". So salvaging your method seems hard, I think the method of using cases as Evariste suggested is the right way to go.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the explanation! Also, another question but wouldn't counting "Geometrry, English, Algebra, History" differ from "English, Geometry, Algebra, History"?

Comment: @mathisfun above it wouldn't, because we are not counting in how many ways the student can choose their SCHEDULE. We are instead counting how many ways we can "choose a program of four courses", regardless of what order he attends the classes. I hope that helped!

Comment: Ohh I see! Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another way to look at the problem.  There are $5$ non-English courses to choose from.  You must choose $3$, which means you must omit $2$.  That would give you $\binom 52$ possibilities of courses to omit from your program, which is $10$ possibilities.

However, one of the possible pairs you're including in this count is the two math courses, and that specific omission is forbidden.  Therefore, there are $10-1=9$ choices of courses that you are permitted to omit, which means that there are $9$ possible programs.

Your solution is wrong because you are double-counting all of the programs with two math courses, and because you are treating programs with the same courses selected in a different order as different programs, when instead order doesn't matter.

Comment: Why the downvote?